# Sublime Text ler arquivo less com a sintaxe do CSS

Tags: sublime-text

Alguém sabe como fazer o Sublime Text abrir arquivo less e reconhecer a sintaxe dele.
Quando eu abro o arquivo .less, aperto <kbd>crt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> e escolho Set Sintax: CSS, mas tenho que fazer isso toda a vez.

Alguém sabe como implantar permanente no Sublime Text 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A sintaxe do `css` é diferente da do `less`, o que você pode e na verdade, o certo a se  fazer é instalar o [**PackageControl**](https://packagecontrol.io/) (já deveria vir incorporado ao sublime xD) e instalar o [`less package`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LESS).